# gource export video error "could not find codec parameters" 

Tags: 11.04, video

I want to output a video of gource, I follow this guide [Creating videos with gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/Videos)
but I get error on video codec. I also use this guide  [enable libx264 support on](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1117283)

This is my error :

> gource -o - | ffmpeg -y -b 3000K -r 60
> -f image2pipe -vcodec ppm -i - -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -threads 0
> gource.mp4
>
> pipe:: could not find codec parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally fixed this problem for me by installing the following packages
(you probably don't need all of them):

libnetpbm10-dev (2:10.0-12.2)

libavfilter1 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1)
libavformat52 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1)
libpostproc51 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1)
libswscale0 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu1.1)

libavcodec-extra-52 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2)
libavutil-extra-50 (4:0.6.2-1ubuntu2)

The complete error I got to start with:

```
[image2pipe @ 0x23036e0]Could not find codec parameters (Video: ppm)
[image2pipe @ 0x23036e0]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
pipe:: could not find codec parameters
```